# Shutdown Multiple Servers From One APC USB Port - Power loss event

Tags: ubuntu, ups, synology, apc

I've got one Ubuntu box and a Synology NAS. Both are connected to the APC UPS, but only one USB, which is connected to the Ubuntu box.

How, specifically, can I get both machines to shut down from a power loss event from one APC USB port?

Comment: You must have a APC Network Management Card on smartslot of the APC UPS. That way you configure Synology Nas to read SNMP messages and enters safe mode in case of power failure. The other way is that one of them that have the usb to send SNMP messages on network

Answer (score 0):

UPS monitoring software such as `apcupsd` or `nut` can handle clients connected by network so that if the primary server (where the UPS is monitored) decides it's time to initiate a shutdown, the clients can be notified to also shutdown.

You first step should be to identify what UPS monitoring software is installed, Once you know that, check the documentation on how to add clients.

Comment: Thanks. I have to check what I installed on the Ubuntu box. Might be apcupsd